# There is olny a README.md in my github

Tags: ubuntu, github

I tried to upload my codes to github by following some tutorial but the last step couldn't be finished. I am using Ubuntu by the way. I am sorry I don't have enough reputation to post links in these command line but I am sure they were correct.

```
han@han-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/chen/project0-1$ git remote add origin 
han@han-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/chen/project0-1$ git push -u origin master
Username for
Password for  
To https://github.com/alvinvinvinvin/CS541-han.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
han@han-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/chen/project0-1$ git remote add origin 
fatal: remote origin already exists.
han@han-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/chen/project0-1$ git push -u origin master
Username for
Password for 
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
Everything up-to-date
han@han-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/chen/project0-1$ git add .
```

As you can see I have tried couple ways to upload codes but there is still only a README.md in my github. I tried to google this problem but there is no clearly related answer. Could you help me out whith it? Thank you.

---

the tutorial said once I entered "git add ." it will add all files in that directory automatically. If it doesn't work is there any easier way to add files? I don't wanna add them one by one because that's too slow.

---

Thanks a lot. By following the order of commands from you I successfully made it. I supposed to keep input git commit and push origin master after git add .. I think that's why. How important it is to insist on getting things done. LOL. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Everything up-to-date" implies there were no changes to upload, have you done

```
git add <filename> // OR git add .
git commit -m"Commit Message"
```

To create a new commit and mark your code for uploading first?

This forms a general update loop:

```
git add .
git commit -m"A message to identify what changes have been made"
git push origin master
```

In turn these functions

1. Add any files that havent' been checked in
2. Create a new commit (think save point) in the projects history
3. Send the new commit to the server where it's backed up and can be pulled to other devices

Comment: the tutorial said once I entered git add . it will add all files in that directory automatically. If it doesn't work is there any easier way to add files? I don't wanna add them one by one because that's too slow.

Comment: `git add .` is fine, as long as you also ran `git commit`. Did you do that?

Comment: @user3582252 Yep, what Chris said `git add .` is fine if you're not fussy about what files get included but you'll need `git commit` too.

Comment: Thanks a lot. By following the order of commands from you I successfully made it. I supposed to keep input git commit and push origin master after git add .. I think that's why. How important it is to insist on getting things done. LOL. Thank you guys.